# How to split navigation and float to each side?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am looking to be able to split my nav headers 3/3, float one set to the left and one to the right, but still have the children drop directly below the parent. I've been struggling quite a bit. Thank you for the help, and please let me know if I can add anything!

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}
ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
left ul li {
  position: relative;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
ul li:hover {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Be Inspired</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Bel Marin Keys</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Belvedere</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tiburon</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">San Francisco</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">San Rafael</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Piedmont</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Planting</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Custom Stonework</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Carpentry</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outdoor Lighting</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Advice &#038; News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, what do you mean by 'set'? "float one set to the left and one to the right." (i've removed some list items so the html isn't quite so long.)

Comment: I would like the Home, Be Inspired, and Service headers/children to be on the right side of the nav panel (it's horizontal), and the Advice & News, About Us, and Contact us headers/children to be on the left side of the panel. I'm building it inside of Pure Drawer, top down slider. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
.superflex{display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-content: stretch;
-ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/RWEVPW

Comment: Not entirely. I'm including a picture of a sketch of what the dropdown door might look like. Thank you for helping! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B43R03zcVRAzVUUyVkhWNzFxWWs/view?usp=sharing